# Queries using UUID in MOngoDB with Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm new to both Node.js and JavaScript in general and I couldn't seem to find a good answer to my question.

I'm trying to write a find query for my MongoDB database from a Node.js server. At first, I was using the `_id` as the standard `ObjectID`, but the project required to swap to UUID. While I managed to assign UUID values to the `_id` fields inside the database, I have no idea how to run a find query. What led me to posting this specific question was that inside mongo, I can run `db.collection.find({_id: new UUID()})` and it works, but in Node.js there is no UUID I can import from mongodb. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

`db.collection.find({_id: new UUID()})` is like asking mongo to *"find some random unique ID"* you haven't seen before. You'll need to know which particular `_id` you'd like to find.

for example on saving to db:

```js
const newUuid = new UUID();
const exampleInstance = new ExampleModel({_id: newUuid });
console.log(newUuid); // you can see the generated UUID. say:a9fd6d30-8614-4eed-90ec-7e7af43ee976
await exampleInstance.save();
```

Then, during find:

```js
const previousUuid = 'a9fd6d30-8614-4eed-90ec-7e7af43ee976'
ExampleModel.find({_id: previousUuid })
```

*note: assuming you're using [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/)*